# Error while adding data in userID in Firebase Swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add data by respective userIDs in Firebase by sign up the user, but it gives me error "`unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`" now I don't know what the matter is. But when I use code without adding `userID` in `ref` respectively the data is added successfully. but when I add `userID` following `ref` then got error.

**SignUp**

```
  let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid


  ref.child("user_registration").child(userID!).setValue(["username": self.fullName.text, "email": self.emailTextField.text,"contact": self.numberText.text, "city": self.myCity.text, "state": self.countryText.text, "gender": genderGroup, "blood": bloodGroup])
```

[image]

Comment: Accept one of the answers pls

Comment: @VladPulichev still looking for answers because the data is not being stored in a UID as i expected

Comment: Whats wrong atm?

Comment: @VladPulichev the data is not bening stored under node of USERID

Comment: Show your database screenshot. And what does print(userID!) show?

Comment: However when i remove UserID and just save under autoID it is saved successfully but i have to save data under USERID help me to accomplish this.

Comment: Add the screenshot of db and print(userID!) befor ref.child(.....).setValue

Comment: Nothing is being stored...

Comment: print this: print((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)

Comment: added snap it was first stored with previous signin ,,,, now nothing bewing stored

Comment: Look at your snapshot. Do you think, that "Optional()" is ok in the node name?..

Comment: What does print this?. print((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)

Comment: @VladPulichev it printed previous signed i.d

Comment: pls. Select what it has printed. full text from console. And add it to comment. Is it so hard?

Comment: Email verified. Signing in...
male
A+
Label
(lldb) finnaly errrorr when i signedout from prevous i.d and then signup

Comment: Sign out. On login page print same print((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!). Then login and print same.

Comment: Profile[1655:20678] [MobileAssetError:29] Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.TextInput.SpellChecker
Email verified. Signing in...

Comment: i.d is not being printed........... :(

Comment: It's another question. Ask it. With full code of your login. Idk. For your question in your topic you got answer. Nil cz user is not logged in. Its pretty hard to answer without full code of login in

Comment: Its good suggestion dear, but i want to get answer this question first, because data is not getting stored under UID

Comment: Ok. ref.child("user_registration").child("ABRAKADABRA").setValue(["Worked": "YES"]. Make this instead of ref.child("user_registration").child(userID!).setValue(["username": self.fullName.text, "email": self.emailTextField.text,"contact": self.numberText.text, "city": self.myCity.text, "state": self.countryText.text, "gender": genderGroup, "blood": bloodGroup])

Comment: yes this is being printed, everything is being printed but except UID this is going in problem

Comment: If it has been added to db -> Your "user is not logged in" when you r trying to save with userId!

Comment: My suggestion is to put a breakpoint on the line ref.child("user_registration").child(........ and look at the data you are using here. And try to find incorrect.

Comment: it performs login but not signup as by doing this brakpoint...

Comment: I'm done. Sorry. I have written, what you need to do. Ask another question with your sign up code. Good luck.

Comment: And another thing. Try to think yourself first of all..

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the error. You are force unwrapping the `userID` which is not a good idea because the user may or may not be logged in when you calling this API. Below changes will resolve your issue.

```
 if let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
     ref.child("user_registration").child(userID).setValue(["username": self.fullName.text, "email": self.emailTextField.text,"contact": self.numberText.text, "city": self.myCity.text, "state": self.countryText.text, "gender": genderGroup, "blood": bloodGroup]
 } else {
     // ask the user to login in
     // present your login view controller
 }
```

Comment: It saves data with previous logged in i.d, i have done log out but then it saves nothing in neither i.d but shows it has been done

Comment: Yes, it does what it suppose to. If the user is not logged In you need to ask him login in `else` block or another way to do is suggested by @vlad.

Comment: dear Rahul data is still not being stored, i think it is optional so?? any help??

Answer (score 1):

Your user is not logged in `=>` error in unwrapping. You need to have something like:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  // FireBase init part
  FIRApp.configure()
  FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = false

  self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

  // Setting initial viewController for user loggedIn?
  if(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil) {
     self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController")
  } else {
     self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginPage")
  }

  return true
```

}

in your `AppDelegate`. It will change your initial view controller to login page, If user is not logged in.

With this code you can force unwrapping.

Hope it helps

Comment: i have defined it but what could be the `MainTabBarController`

Comment: @Xcodian your main controller with the start of your logic

Comment: I have navigation controller at start and then Login Page

Comment: @Xcodian its controller for which you are coming after login

Comment: it is ok now i have defined the `tabbarcontroler` as `Homecontroller` that is after login the first screen appear

Comment: @Xcodian nice:)

Comment: @Xcodian pls, stop calling me sir:) What is the problem atm? If your have logged in, you should be ready to force unwrapping and it should not show you any errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144916/discussion-between-xcodian-and-vlad-pulichev).