# Data is not being inserted under the node of user UID in Firebase in Swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When I save data under `userID` the data is not being stored into the Firebase and give error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`, however when I use `childByAutoID` the data is being stored successfully. Help me to save under `userID` node. Here I have explained that when I create the user under signup action this is happening.

```
@IBAction func createAccountAction(_ sender: Any) {

    if self.emailTextField.text == "" || self.passwordTextField.text == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter your email and password", preferredStyle: .alert) 
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction) 
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)   
    } else if (self.passwordTextField.text != self.retypePasswordfield.text) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Password does not match", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction) 
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        ref.child("user_registration").setValue(["username": self.fullName.text, "email": self.emailTextField.text,"contact": self.numberText.text, "city": self.myCity.text, "state": self.countryText.text, "gender": genderGroup, "blood": bloodGroup])

        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil {
                FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
                })  
                print("You have successfully signed up")
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Successful!", message: "Email Verification link sent", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let alertActionOkay = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default) { (action) in
                    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginFirstViewController")
                    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                alertController.addAction(alertActionOkay)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: your user is not authenticated , so first authenticate it. This might be issue. Because it does not getting current user.

Comment: to help with your debugging, you can split lines like this into sections so that you can see where the error is happening.  extract the uid into a variable, define the reference, extract the textfield data, and then put it all together.  That said, as @dahiya_boy suggests, you should always start with anything you are unwrapping and it does look like the current user is not authenticated

Comment: @dahiya_boy the user is signing up so user is not authenticated

Comment: @Russell the user is signing up so user is not authenticated, i have do the same as you said but still same error because user is for sign up . any suggestion?

Comment: You should call this method in the Auth delegate method. One of them will tell you when the user successfully signed up and give you back that user

Comment: once you create a new user, you should have the uid defined for current user - are you sure that part is working correctly?  Perhaps you could show us the relevant code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while adding data in userID in Firebase Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129482/error-while-adding-data-in-userid-in-firebase-swift-3)

Comment: @Russell i am creating the user under signup button and during signup action i have defined this code

Comment: @VladPulichev yes dear but still no helpful answer i got

Comment: => Start a bounty :)

Comment: @VladPulichev trying to start but have no reputation to offer bounty at least i should have 75 then i will eligible

Comment: It's not clear where there error is occurring. You need to add a break in the code and step through it line by line and tell us what line it causing the error. I would start by adding a break to this line *ref.child("user_registration")* and then step through. Once you provided that info, we can help.

Answer (score 1):

**Only for reference**

This is the current working code for me

On signUp Button

```
 // Create new User
            FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: self.tfEmail.text!, password: self.tfPassword.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

                if error == nil{ // IF NO ERROR

                    let astrContact = self.strDialCode + " " + self.tfMobileNumber.text!

                    // Dict to add user data in firebase Db
                    let aDBDict : [String : String] = ["userName": self.tfFullName.text!,
                                                       "userEmail": self.tfEmail.text!,
                                                       "userContact": astrContact,
                                                       "userCountry": self.strCode,
                                                       "userID": (user?.uid)!]


                    // Add data in DB
                    ref?.child("Customer/\(String(describing: (user?.uid)!)/userProfileDetails").setValue(aDBDict)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                        // goto home VC
                        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let navController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainController")

                        if let window = AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().window {
                            window.rootViewController = navController
                        }
                    })
                }
                else{ // If error in creating new user
                    print("error in creating new user")
                    print(error!)
                }
            })
```

In appDelegate

```
extension AppDelegate {

    class func getAppDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }
}
```

Comment: getAppDelegate() is undefined?

Comment: value of appdelegate has no member `userdetails`

Comment: value of appdelegeate has no member `uID`

Comment: I have removed some code work which is not relevant to you. These are the var declared in AppDelegate. So use new edited code.

Comment: have you any idea of that variable?

Comment: Yeah I have bcz I created them.

Comment: so would you write them here or update them in question please!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145107/discussion-between-dahiya-boy-and-xcodian).